How to use perf to find the heavy read and write parts of a program
I want to use perf to find out how many instructions will cause a large number of cache or memory accesses. Is there any good sampling method or usage method? My current sampling is
perf record -e cycles -c 1000 -e cache-references -o output -- /path/to/myprogram

or
perf record -e cache-references -F 999 -- /path/to/myprogram

My current idea is to sample the total cache-reference every 1000 instructions, so that I can know how many 1000 instructions will cause a peak in memory access, but I don't know how to implement it
当前我的采样结果使用
perf script -i output

查看
# ========
# captured on    : Mon Dec  2 16:40:50 2024
# header version : 1
# data offset    : 376
# data size      : 2667368
# feat offset    : 2667744
# hostname : DESKTOP-1EUOCIC
# os release : 5.15.167.4-microsoft-standard-WSL2
# perf version : 5.15.167.4.g6ac7abbd97a0
# arch : x86_64
# nrcpus online : 16
# nrcpus avail : 16
# cpudesc : 11th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-11800H @ 2.30GHz
# cpuid : GenuineIntel,6,141,1
# total memory : 8014164 kB
# cmdline : /usr/local/bin/perf record -e cache-references -F 999 -o output -- ./perlbench_r_base.mytest-m64 -I./lib checkspam.pl 2500 5 25 11 150 1 1 1 1 
# event : name = cache-references, , id = { 2458, 2459, 2460, 2461, 2462, 2463, 2464, 2465, 2466, 2467, 2468, 2469, 2470, 2471, 2472, 2473 }, size = 128, config = 0x2, {>
# CPU_TOPOLOGY info available, use -I to display
# pmu mappings: software = 1, uprobe = 7, cpu = 4, breakpoint = 5, tracepoint = 2, kprobe = 6, msr = 8
# CACHE info available, use -I to display
# time of first sample : 26703.215422
# time of last sample : 26815.523288
# sample duration : 112307.866 ms
# cpu pmu capabilities: branches=32, max_precise=0, pmu_name=icelake
# missing features: TRACING_DATA NUMA_TOPOLOGY BRANCH_STACK GROUP_DESC AUXTRACE STAT MEM_TOPOLOGY CLOCKID DIR_FORMAT COMPRESSED CLOCK_DATA HYBRID_TOPOLOGY HYBRID_CPU_PMU>
# ========
#
       perf-exec 15358 26703.215422:          1 cache-references:  ffffffff98268a92
 perlbench_r_bas 15358 26703.216321:          1 cache-references:  ffffffff98f2d609
 perlbench_r_bas 15358 26703.217026:          1 cache-references:  ffffffff98f2d609
 perlbench_r_bas 15358 26703.217456:          1 cache-references:  ffffffff9826d181
 perlbench_r_bas 15358 26703.217738:          2 cache-references:  ffffffff9826d181
 perlbench_r_bas 15358 26703.218018:          3 cache-references:  ffffffff9813838f
 perlbench_r_bas 15358 26703.218409:          4 cache-references:  ffffffff98161180
 perlbench_r_bas 15358 26703.218861:          5 cache-references:  ffffffff9813837f
 perlbench_r_bas 15358 26703.219142:          6 cache-references:  ffffffff98f2d702
 perlbench_r_bas 15358 26703.219418:          8 cache-references:  ffffffff981605a1
 perlbench_r_bas 15358 26703.219422:         11 cache-references:  ffffffff981605a1
 perlbench_r_bas 15358 26703.219425:        346 cache-references:  ffffffff982c2100
 perlbench_r_bas 15358 26703.219430:      15765 cache-references:      5601df0141bf 
 perlbench_r_bas 15358 26703.220397:     338609 cache-references:  ffffffff983e9b45
 perlbench_r_bas 15358 26703.231550:     301439 cache-references:      5601defed5b0 
 perlbench_r_bas 15358 26703.241884:     237371 cache-references:      5601defb970d 
 perlbench_r_bas 15358 26703.252191:     210575 cache-references:      5601def70029 
 perlbench_r_bas 15358 26703.260651:     169527 cache-references:      7f3ad66e97ea
 perlbench_r_bas 15358 26703.265484:     150845 cache-references:  ffffffff98316161
 perlbench_r_bas 15358 26703.270947:     122846 cache-references:      5601def671ac


What's with the Chinese text? Can you please remove it?
